# Giving closed question as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

I found to my surprise that a closed question can be given as the duplicate-of when voting to close. Is this desired/expected behavior? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669624/clicking-an-element-in-a-page-and-see-the-related-javascript-codes).